# Regex for unsigned number (float and integer)

Tags: regex

i need to setup a regex that match like the following number:

```
5
6.4
1.22
```

the number must be unsigned, interger or float and max 2 decimal number. I'm in trouble, how is it possible?

Comment: What seems to be a problem? You need one or more digits, followed by an optional decimal point followed by 0 to 2 digits.

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html Specify clearly the tool (regular expressions are different in different tools).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible

```
(?:\d*\.)?\d+
```

this is more relevant to your question

```
^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

matches: 1, 1.2, 1.23, .45 but not .678 or 9.101

Comment: allow to digit? where do you use the regex?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"^\d+\.?\d*$"
```

^ = start
$ = end
\d = number
. = dot
? = optional last token
+ = one or more
* = zero or more

Answer (score 0):

```
\d+(\.\d{1,2})?
```

It allows all of your cases and nothing else.

- `?` after things makes them optional
- `\d` matches any digit
- `+` after things means there need to be one or more of them
- `.` matches all characters, therefore it is escaped here to match the literal dot

I used brackets here to make the whole decimal part starting with the dot optional.
The numbers in the curly brackets mean that those counts of the previous token are allowed, so we allow one or two digits here.

The `+` is important, so no empty strings are matched.

If you need this to be the only thing in the string also add `^` and `$` like this:

```
^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```